# Is there a way to prove if an Egyptian fraction is optimal?

Tags: optimization, rational-numbers, egyptian-fractions

Egyptian fractions are the representation of a rational number (for example, $\frac{61}{66}$) as a sum of reciprocals of integers (with that example, $2^{-1} + 3^{-1} + 11^{-1}$), a.k.a. unit fractions ($\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{11}$). Typically, there is an additional restriction that each integer be unique, so $\frac{2}{3}$ would be properly represented as $2^{-1} + 6^{-1}$ but not as $3^{-1} + 3^{-1}$.

For any rational number $\frac{p}{q}$, there exist infinitely many Egyptian fractions of the form $a_1^{-1} + a_2^{-1} + a_3^{-1} + ... + a_n^{-1}$.

**I am interested in finding the *optimal* Egyptian fraction forms for a given rational number, with *optimal* being defined as *the lowest possible sum of the constituent integers* ($a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + ... + a_n$)**. I do not require the restriction that each integer be unique. Thus, by this metric, $3^{-1} + 3^{-1}$ would be better than $2^{-1} + 6^{-1}$ as a representation of $\frac{2}{3}$, because the value of $3 + 3$ is less than the value of $2 + 6$.

As another example, the number $\frac{13}{12}$ can be represented as $1^{-1} + 12^{-1}$ and as $2^{-1} + 3^{-1} + 4^{-1}$, with the latter representation being more-optimal than the former.

**Is there a way to prove that a given Egyptian fraction is optimal, or is *not* optimal, given this definition?**

We do have an upper bound for the sum of the constituent integers. For the rational number $\frac{p}{q}$, an optimal Egyptian fraction form must sum to less than or equal to $p × q$, because (without a restriction that all integers must be unique) we can represent $\frac{p}{q}$ as $q^{-1}$ added to itself $p$ times. So for any number $\frac{p}{q}$ and Egyptian fraction form $a_1^{-1} + a_2^{-1} + a_3^{-1} + ... + a_n^{-1}$, if the sum $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + ... + a_n$ is greater than $p × q$ we know for sure that it is *not* optimal. However, there are many rational numbers with Egyptian fraction forms that are *better* than $p × q$, so this on its own isn't proof of optimalness.

Comment: This page says "there is no known algorithm for optimal Egyptian fractions.": https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/cody/problems/2838-optimum-egyptian-fractions

Comment: Do you want an efficient algorithm, or any algorithm at all?  Because there's certainly a silly algorithm:  given an Egyptian fraction $p/q = a_1^{-1} + \cdots + a_n^{-1}$, iterate over all of the finitely many partitions $(b_1, \dots, b_m)$ with $\sum_i b_i < \sum_j a_j$, and check for each one whether $b_1^{-1} + \cdots + b_m^{-1} = p/q$.

Comment: @RaviFernando I would like something a little more efficient than that, if possible. 